# Java - run a java program with args within a Java program

Tags: java, swing, csv, file-io

I have a JButton which opens JFileChooser and that in turn selects a file into a variable called "file".

I want to rename the selected file to "Best.html" and then provide it to [TableToCSV.java](http://wush.net/svn/mindprod/com/mindprod/csv/TableToCSV.java) (java TableToCSV.class Best.html), which will convert the selected file to a .csv format.

Here is my code -

```
final JFileChooser  fileDialog = new JFileChooser();
    JButton btnInputFile = new JButton("Input File");
    btnInputFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            int returnVal = fileDialog.showOpenDialog(rootPane);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
               java.io.File file = fileDialog.getSelectedFile();

            }

        }
    });
```

**Note** - I want to rename because the TableToCSV.java file only inputs file with a .html extension.

**Note** - TableToCSV.java lies in the same folder as my java program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options...

### You Could...

Use `TableToCSV` `main` method...

```
TableToCSV.main(new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()});
```

Which is essentially the same as calling it from the command line

### Or You Could...

Use the `TableToCSV` constructor...

```
TableToCSV tableToCSV = new TableToCSV( file, ',', '\"', '#', CSV.UTF8Charset );
```

The problem with this is, `TableToCSV` is expecting a file name with a 4 char extension...So if you were to pass it a `File` with an extension of `.txt`, the resulting file won't appear as you expect it and could actually lead to some danger.

In this case you could use

```
String name = file.getName();
name = name.subString(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));
name += ".html";
File newFile = new File(file.getParentFile(), name);
if (file.renameTo(newFile)) {
    TableToCSV tableToCSV = new TableToCSV( newFile, ',', '\"', '#', CSV.UTF8Charset );
}
```

But I do hate renaming files...

Answer (score 0):

Why not call the constructor of `TableToCSV`? Like in line 192 of [TableToCSV.java](http://wush.net/svn/mindprod/com/mindprod/csv/TableToCSV.java)?

```
 new TableToCSV( file, ',', '\"', '#', CSV.UTF8Charset );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
final JFileChooser  fileDialog = new JFileChooser();
        JButton btnInputFile = new JButton("Input File");
        btnInputFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                int returnVal = fileDialog.showOpenDialog(rootPane);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                   java.io.File file = fileDialog.getSelectedFile();
                   File newFile = new File("Best.html")
                   com.mindprod.TableToCSV(file.renameTo(newfile), ... );
                }

            }
        });
```